# Convert sql select where in to Laravel query builder

Tags: sql, laravel

my array from `$stemp [hasil] => 20,8,24`

my sql query `SELECT * FROM 'objek' WHERE objek.id IN ('20','8','24')`

I'm try `DB::select("SELECT * FROM 'objek' WHERE objek.id IN ('$stemp')");`

It's not work, and get error Array to string conversion.

Comment: You can use `Laravel's whereIn()` method for this as I mentioned in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The clean solution

Use the Laravel Query Builder methods to make your query:

```
DB::table('objek')->select('*')->whereIn('id', [20, 8, 4])->get()
```

Note that the `->select('*')` isn't required since the query builder selects `*` by default. So you can remove it:

```
DB::table('objek')->whereIn('id', [20, 8, 4])->get()
```

## The bad (but working) solution

Since `$stemp` is a array, you need to convert it to an string before concatenating it on the query:

```
$stemp = [20, 8, 24];

// Put your ID's between Quotes (not necessary actually, but 
// I'm just trying to replicate the desired query)
$stemp = array_map(function($id) { return "'{$id}'"; }, $stemp); // ['20','8','24']

// Glue the pieces using a comma
$stemp = implode(',', $stemp); // string(13) "'20','8','24'"

// Now you can concatenate it to your query
// Note that you shouldn't use the single quotes between $stemp
// since your quotes are already on each number.
DB::select("SELECT * FROM 'objek' WHERE objek.id IN ($stemp)");
```

### Why this is a bad solution?

Doing the query by this way can open a [SQL Injection vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work), so you must do either:

- Trust on your data source, eg: Your `$stemp` come from another queries that you trust the content
- Sanitize your data to remove malicious code

### Why the first solution is better?

- Your code turns more human readable
- Laravel Query Builder automatically sanitize your input

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this.

```
DB::table('objek')
    ->select('*')
    ->whereIn('id', $stemp)
    ->get();
```

You can find more info on `Laravel Where` here in [laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

But I'd prefer using `Eloquent` rather than using `DB::table()`.

you can create a model like `Objek` and extend it with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Objek extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Objek';

}
```

Then you can do,

```
Objek::select('*')
    ->whereIn('id', $stemp)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I get error `Object of class stdClass could not be convertes to string`

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 747

Comment: Which helpers.php file, there are couple of helpers.php in Laravel. And when you post you should be descriptive, or otherwise we won't be able to figure it out. And I also feels that this error is not relevant to this question. It could be generated from somewhere else. In that case you should ether do your research or post it as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what way you want to do

If Model is present

```
Model::whereIn('columnName', $array)->get()
```

To query table

```
DB::table('users')->whereIn('columnName', $array)->get();
```

If you want more have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
DB::table('objek')->whereIn('objek.id',array('20','8','24'))->get();
```

Hope this work for you!